# ansible playbook error was: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.mgmt.monitor.version' although the module is installed

Tags: python-3.x, azure, ansible, ansible-2.x

After upgrading ansible to version 2.10.5 and python3.8.10 my playbook.yml fails with this error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.mgmt.monitor.version'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"attempts": 1, "changed": false, "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (ansible[azure] (azure >= 2.0.0)) on certrenewplay's Python /usr/bin/python3`
```

The module is there if I run `python3 -c  "import azure.mgmt.monitor"` and if I run `pip3 list` I see it installed as `azure-mgmt-monitor==2.0.0`

The exact part of the playbook code that is erroring is this:

```yaml
 - name: Create _acme-challenge record for zone "{{ env_name_dot }}"
   azure_rm_dnsrecordset:
    subscription_id: "{{ mgmt_subscription }}"
    client_id: "{{ mgmt_vault_azure_client_id }}"
    tenant: "{{ mgmt_vault_azure_tenant_id }}"
    secret: "{{ mgmt_vault_azure_client_secret }}"
    resource_group: "{{ mgmt_rg }}"
    relative_name: "_acme-challenge.{{ env_name }}"
    zone_name: "{{ dns_zone_name }}.{{ dns_zone_domain }}"
    record_type: TXT
    state: present
    records:
      - entry: "{{ cn_challenge_data }}"
    time_to_live: 60
  when: dns_zone_name != 'activedrop'
  register: add_record
  retries: 1
  delay: 10

  until: add_record is succeeded
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong-can anyone advise please or help me on this please?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This same issue happened to me because Ansible now ships with its own version of the Azure collection and it was conflicting with the version I had manually installed in my own playbook using the "ansible-galaxy collection" command.

What I suggest you do is only use the version that ships with Ansible and then install its requirements like so:

```
pip install -r /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/requirements-azure.txt
```

It is easier to setup correctly on a freshly installed system (e.g in Docker) than it is to fix a broken system.

Comment: you could also use venv. New python doesnt even let you install packages on system level anymore without fuss.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you did not follow the instruction about installing azure collection from https://github.com/ansible-collections/azure

Installing collection itself does not install python dependencies, these are installed using python pip and you need to be sure you are installing them inside the same python (v)env where ansible is installed, or ansible will give you the error that you seen when trying to load the module.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the azure-mgmt-monitor package is bugged, even on 3.0.0 to not properly create a version submodule. Haven't been able to track down exactly where in the code it's busted, but it is and there is a direct import of that submodule in the Ansible Galaxy module causing it to fail. Unfortunately you should use the Azure CLI at this time and forget about using `azure_rm`

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30822269)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to add `delegate_to: 127.0.0.1`. The package was installed on my local machine, but not the remote server, but by default Ansible wanted to `from azure.mgmt.core.tools` on the remote server, where the azure requirements were not installed.